# Google storage permissions Access denied

Tags: google-cloud-platform, permissions, cloud, storage, bucket

I have a storage bucket with storage object viewer set to allAuthenticatedUsers. When trying to access (https://storage.googleapis.com/Myapphere) I get access denied even though I am signed in. The only way I can access is if I set it to allUsers, which is not what I want. I want all authenticated users (including myself) and anyone I add. Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: The "allAuthenticated users" scope will only work for users with Google Account holders. If users do not have a Google account, then this scope will not work. You can read more about the different ACLs [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists#scopes).

Comment: What account (Google, etc.) are you signed in with?

Comment: I am logged in, so why wouldn't that work ? I can check email , manage the cloud settings , check my photos etc.. So I assume I am logged into Google

Comment: Are you using the public link provided to view the object or are you trying to view it from within the bucket directly?

Comment: I do not have dns setup, nor do I want to for this purpose. I am accessing like    https://storage.googleapis.com/mybucket/myobect.html ( of course these aren't the actual names ). Works like a charm but when I restrict to auth'd users I get access denied and I'd prefer it not be open to the public

Comment: It doesnt sound like expected behavior from the details provided. I would suggest creating a [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187161&template=1162660) for further investigation.